# INESRT INTO a table from three SELECT statements

Tags: sql, insert

The first select populates countOfActivePlans:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.txtprogram) AS countOfActivePlans, c.txtLevel1
FROM tblOfferings a, tblClaims b, tblRetailers c
WHERE a.ysnActive=1 
      AND c.intRetailer=b.intRetailer 
      AND c.intRetailer=a.intRetailer
GROUP BY c.txtLevel1
ORDER BY c.txtLevel1
```

The second select populates plansWithActivity:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.txtProgram) AS plansWithActivity,   c.txtLevel1
FROM tblClaims a, tblOfferings b, tblRetailers 
WHERE a.intOffering=b.intOffering 
      AND c.intRetailer=a.intRetailer 
      AND c.intRetailer=b.intRetailer
GROUP BY c.txtlevel1
ORDER BY c.txtLevel1
```

The third populates Approved, Denied, and sumOfcurPaid:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.dblTransaction) AS invoicesSubmitted, SUM(curPaid) AS sumOfcurPaid, b.txtLevel1, 
       CASE WHEN a.intTransCode=0 THEN 'Denied' 
            WHEN a.intTransCode=1 THEN 'Approved' 
            ELSE 'Reissued' 
       END AS txtLabel
FROM tblClaims a, tblRetailers b, tbLTransCode c
WHERE a.intRetailer=b.intRetailer 
      AND a.intTransCode=c.intTransCode
GROUP BY b.txtLevel1, 
       CASE WHEN a.intTransCode=0 THEN 'Denied' 
            WHEN a.intTransCode=1 THEN 'Approved' 
            ELSE 'Reissued' 
       END
ORDER BY b.txtLevel1 asc
```

The table is below.

How can I make this one `INSERT` that populates the table?

```
Area countOfActivePlans plansWithActivity   approved    denied  sumOfCurPaid
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CE   237                230                 89898       11438   1238152.858
NE   189                178                 54159       5667    1665176.757
SE   177                165                 58675       5873    1406241.758
SW   118                111                 32450       6934    1329101.503
WE   152                145                 40266       3473    529956.6875
```

Comment: Does txtLevel1 hold an area code?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO
  MyTable (Area,countOfActivePlans,plansWithActivity,approved,denied,sumOfCurPaid)
SELECT
  f1.Area, f2.countOfActivePlans, f3.plansWithActivity, f4.Approved, f4.Denied, f4.sumOfcurPaid,
FROM
  (SELECT [THAT GETS THE AREA])           AS f1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.txtprogram) AS countOfActivePlans, c.txtLevel1
    FROM tblOfferings a, tblClaims b, tblRetailers c
    WHERE a.ysnActive=1 
      AND c.intRetailer=b.intRetailer 
      AND c.intRetailer=a.intRetailer
    GROUP BY c.txtLevel1
    ORDER BY c.txtLevel1 )           AS f2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.txtProgram) AS plansWithActivity,   c.txtLevel1
    FROM tblClaims a, tblOfferings b, tblRetailers c
    WHERE a.intOffering=b.intOffering 
      AND c.intRetailer=a.intRetailer 
      AND c.intRetailer=b.intRetailer
    GROUP BY c.txtlevel1
    ORDER BY c.txtLevel1) AS f3
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(a.dblTransaction) AS invoicesSubmitted, SUM(curPaid) AS sumOfcurPaid, b.txtLevel1, 
   CASE WHEN a.intTransCode=0 THEN 'Denied' 
        WHEN a.intTransCode=1 THEN 'Approved' 
        ELSE 'Reissued' 
   END AS txtLabel
   FROM tblClaims a, tblRetailers b, tbLTransCode c
   WHERE a.intRetailer=b.intRetailer 
    AND a.intTransCode=c.intTransCode
   GROUP BY b.txtLevel1, 
   CASE WHEN a.intTransCode=0 THEN 'Denied' 
        WHEN a.intTransCode=1 THEN 'Approved' 
        ELSE 'Reissued' 
   END
   ORDER BY b.txtLevel1 asc)           AS f4
```

I think this will be ok, but I have included the basic idea below just incase I got some code wrong above.

```
INSERT INTO
  MyTable (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)
SELECT
  f1.col1, f2.col2, f3.col3, f4.col4, f4.col5, f4.col6
FROM
  (SELECT Col1 FROM QUERYWITHAREA)    AS f1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col2 FROM QUERY1)           AS f2
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col3 FROM QUERY2)           AS f3
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT Col4,Col5,Col6 FROM QUERY3) AS f4
```

Hope this helps, sorry if the first example isn't perfect, its a guide to help you. To be honest I would be tempted to put each query from your question in to a function and call each function in the style above.

Comment: After few cosmetic fixes..i get below error                          Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The column prefix 'c' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: @ChaunnahRailey - thought you might, I would try and code it yourself based on the second example I give and I would put each of your SELECTS in functions.

Comment: @ChaunnahRailey - try "FROM tblClaims a, tblOfferings b, tblRetailers c" in f3, the 'c' was missing in your code above. My attempt above has that change in now.